# Move directory from local machine (linux) to SSH server

Tags: linux, ssh

i am trying to move one my folders from my local machine to my ssh connection.

i have been trying with the following command:

```
scp -r /var/www/foo/ root@******/var/www/foo
```

However when i try i get the following error messag

```
cp: cannot create directory ‘root@*****/var/www/foo’: No such file or directory
```

So how can i move the folder to my server?

**Note**

It might be worth mentioning that it is a CentOs 6 server

**Update**

RIght now i get the following:

```
    scp -r /var/www/foo/ root@****:/var/www/foo
root@*****'s password: 
bash: scp: command not found
```

Comment: Would it be `scp -r /var/www/foo/ root@******:/var/www/foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
scp -r /var/www/foo/ root@******:/var/www/foo
```

The `:` after the hostname is important.

Comment: it says cp: ‘/var/www/foo/’ and ‘/var/www/foo’ are the same file

Comment: The target directory needs to exist.

Comment: now i get: cp: cannot copy a directory, ‘/var/www/foo/’, into itself, ‘/var/www/foo/’

Comment: Use scp not cp.

Comment: i am using scp but i just saw it is just moving it from my one local folder to another and not from local to remote

Comment: Check my update please

Comment: check in the destination if the opensssh-clients package is installed.